# PHP Time Difference - diff

Tags: php, date, time, diff

I have utilised some code already found on another question.

```
<? 

$start_date = new DateTime('now');
$timestamp = strtotime( $nt['last_seen'] );
$since_start = $start_date->diff($timestamp);

echo $since_start->i.' minutes<br>';
echo $since_start->s.' seconds<br>';

?>
```

This does not seem to work ?? the timestamp is pulled in from mysql statement in the format.

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss
```

Comment: simple: `$since_start = date_create('now')->diff(date_create($nt['last_seen']));`

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter in [`diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method expects a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) object, but you're supplying a Unix timestamp instead.

Use the following code instead:

```
$start_date = new DateTime('now');
$end_date = new DateTime($nt['last_seen']);
$since_start = $start_date->diff($end_date);

echo $since_start->format('%i').' minutes<br>';
echo $since_start->format('%s').' seconds<br>';
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/55098)

---

As Glavić notes in the comment below, it's possible to create a `DateTime` object from a Unix timestamp, too:

```
$date = new DateTime("@$timestamp"); // $timestamp is astring -- eg: 1382025097
```

But it is not necessary in this case, and the first method should work just fine.

Comment: If `strtotime` can convert to timestamp, then DateTime should also `new DateTime($nt['last_seen'])`. Plus, DateTime can accept timestamp like `new DateTime('@timestampNumber')`

Comment: @Glavić: I didn't test the code before posting. Updated the answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$start_date = new DateTime('now');
$timestamp = new DateTime($nt['last_seen']);
$since_start = $start_date->diff($timestamp);

echo $since_start->format('%m').' minutes<br>';
echo $since_start->format('%s').' seconds<br>';
```

you need to cast your $timestamp as a new DateTime something like the above

I have a couple of wrapper functions I use look at the db date diff one sql query if you're pulling your $timestamp from the database then there's no reason you can't do the diff in your master query and completely remove the need to do it in PHP after.

```
/** 
* Date Diff between now and submitted data
* @param - $date - takes current date
* @return int number of days between inputted dates +ve numbers are start date in past -ve numbers are end date in future of now()
*/
function daves_date_diff($date) {
    $start = new DateTime($date);
    $today = new DateTime();
    $diff = $start->diff($today);
    return $diff->format('%d');
}
/**
* Database select based date diff as its more reliable than using php date diffs
* @param - $date - date string in mysql format of date to diff against
* @return - int - number of days date is different from now
*/
function db_date_diff($date) {
    global $db;
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->mysqli,$date);
    $returneddiff = $db->queryUniqueObject("SELECT DATEDIFF('$date',NOW()) as DateDiff",ENABLE_DEBUG);
    return $returneddiff->DateDiff;
}
```